# Problema al pasar datos de una controlador de Laravel a una vista con Vue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

Estoy pasando unos datos desde un controlador en el metodo index:

```
public function index() {
    $variable = Modelo::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('vista', compact('variable'));
}
```

y los estoy recibiendo en esta vista:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="value in values">
        <td>@{{ value.id }}</td>
        <td>@{{ value.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Y el código vue es el siguiente:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        values: []
    },
    created: function() {
        this.getVaues()
    },
    methods: {
        getValues: function() {
            var url= 'uri';
            axios.get(url).then(response => {
                this.values = response.data
            });
        }
    }
});
```

El problema es que los datos que se guardan el la lista "values" del código Vue es un marcado html, pero si desde el controlador solo devuelvo los datos(sin la vista) así:

```
return Modelo::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

confirmo que evidentemente si me trae los datos de la BD, pero no se como pasarlos a la vista.

Esto es lo que se guarda en la lista "values" del código Vue y debería guardarse un JSON con los datos obtenidos de la BD con el controlador.
[image: Esto es lo que me devuelve]

Comment: No veo la variable "ministries" por ningún lado.

Comment: @Shaz acabo de editar la pregunta para renombrar las variables y hacer una poco mas general la pregunta la variable "ministries" la renombre por "values"

Comment: Asumo que haces una llamada ajax al método que muestras arriba que incluye `$variable` y luego ahí intentas mostrar los valores. ¿Podríamos ver que es lo que contienen value.id y value.name? y/o un ejemplo de los datos que entrega el request ajax.

Comment: Pues no se a lo que te refieres cuando dices que si hago la llamada ajax al método, de hecho acabo de empezar a aprender estas tecnologías y tal vez es eso que dices, lo de la llama al método ajax, lo que que me hace falta y con respecto a los valores que contienen "value.id" y "value.name" pues no contienen nada porque lo que se guarda en "values" es un marcado html entonces no tiene las propiedades "id" y "name".

Comment: En ese orden de ideas no entiendo lo que intentas hacer, si dices que traes un html que sabes que no tiene las propiedades id y name, ¿entonces qué intentas mostrar? ¿cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Si creo que no me explique bien, lo que intento mostrar son los datos que tengo un mi base da datos, la tabla a la que hago la consulta contiene esos campos "id" y "name" y el problema es que me debería devolver un JSON que se guarde en la lista "values" y así poder acceder a las propiedades con "values.id" y "values.name" pero en vez del JSON lo que me devuelve es un HTML

Comment: Pareciera que en "ministerios" lo que hay es un error de Laravel (lo que se ve es el html de la excepción), tendrías que revisar en la pestaña "network" de chrome que código está entregando dicha consulta ajax (la que haces con axios) y también revisar el log de Laravel.

Comment: @Shaz El código que me devuelve mi escript es un 304 Not Modified así que no da un error y ya revise el log de Laravel y no tiene nada tampoco y analizando bien el HTML que me devuelve no es un excepción si no que es el HTML de la vista a la que estoy mandando los datos

Comment: Entonces lo que debes devolver no es una vista si lo que quieres es mostrar las variables id y name con Vue. Debes devolver un simple resultado de eloquent, voy a escribir una respuesta que te sirva como guía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas mostrar algunas variables con Vue, debes retornar entonces un JSON desde Laravel, lo cual normalmente se hace automáticamente con Eloquent:

```
public function index()
{
    return Modelo::select('id', 'name')
                   ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                   ->get();
}
```

En caso que por algún motivo no generara el JSON, puedes usar el método `->toJson()`

Ya en Vue debería funcionarte el código que tienes actualmente.

Comment: Ya lo había probado así y funciona pero solo para cargar los datos en la vista actual pero lo que quiero es que en la "vista A" tenga un enlace que al hacer click en el me lleve a la "vista B" y muestre los resultados obtenidos en la "vista B".

Comment: ¿cuál enlace? No veo ningún enlace tu código ¿cuál es la vista A y cuál la B? esa parte no la habías explicado....

Comment: En ese caso marcare como solucionado y haré otra pregunta